# /review should not include posts migrated to other sites

Tags: bug, status-declined, review, migrated-questions

Using `/review` (on SF), I came across a post that should have been on the meta site. I clicked through to use the new `flag->doesn't belong` dialog, but then the auto-redirect kicked in and I was on the meta site! The question had already been migrated, which is why it was closed on the `/review` for the <strike>parent</strike> main site.

Link copied from question title in `/review`:
https://serverfault.com/questions/215563/how-can-i-accept-the-answer-offered-to-my-qns-closed

Answer (score 4):

There is a slight timing issue here, if a post is deleted it may show up in /review for 10 minutes to an hour due to caching. Bumping the /review cache every time a post is deleted may be a bit expensive.

I will look to see if we can bounce stuff off the list once deleted, it may through off paging a bit.

Comment: The post I linked was migrated Dec 23rd, 2010 and so I assumed that migrated question were _never_ removed from the /review. I've got no problem with the cache taking a while to catch up.

Comment: @yhw42 ah ... I follow ... it was closed ... but not deleted ... will see if I can add closed as a global filter to /review ... never show closed questions or answers

Comment: that would be awesome.

Comment: Harder than originally thought? I just got caught out by this too.