# When are closed questions removed from review?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, review

When are closed questions removed from `/review`?  It seems rather pointless to take up a review slot for a question that is already closed and has multiple downvotes.

In essence the community has already acted on closed questions, why do I need to review it?

Comment: Related topic on allowing to mark posts as reviewed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them .Though closed questions should certainly be automatically removed from /review

Comment: Hey @C.Ross! Related question I asked about migrated questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76637/review-should-not-include-posts-migrated-to-other-sites. See waffles' response to my comment on the answer.

Comment: +1 I also found this baffling.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of three reasons for keeping closed questions under `/review`:

- It's easier to code that way
- [It's really only an issue on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts/94569#94569)
- It's a chance for the community to cast reopen votes

These all seem sensible enough to me (especially the last one).