# Should moderator deleted messages be showing in /review?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

If a moderator has already handled the post, is there any reason for it to be showing up in the review section? (I was looking at the low quality tab)

[image: Post]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching [(for 10 minutes to an hour)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76637/review-should-not-include-posts-migrated-to-other-sites/77160#77160) is the likely cause here.

Comment: http://twitter.com/#!/balpha/status/38717485729456128