# Mod deleted post re-appearing in /review

Tags: bug, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Review System showing deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143531/new-review-system-showing-deleted-answer)

I've just [reviewed a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/609156) from the "low quality posts" queue which appears to have been mod-deleted 2 days ago.

[image: screenshot]

The post was not marked "deleted" during the review process so I suspect this is not an intended behaviour.

**Update:** It [just happened again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/609197), this time for a post that was deleted more than 2 weeks ago. (A random walk through the [review history page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) reveals [several](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/608539) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/609007) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/608400))

[Several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82046/should-moderator-deleted-messages-be-showing-in-review) [incarnations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108833/deleted-answer-showing-up-in-the-review-tab) of this have surfaced before and the response for those were -- no surprises here -- "Caching".

Two weeks is a rather long time for a caching issue, [no](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/26630549.jpg)?

Comment: [New Review System showing deleted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143531/new-review-system-showing-deleted-answer)

Comment: [Aha!](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/001/384/Atrapitis.gif) Those sneaky b....

Comment: That has a different meaning in Anime... :)

Comment: I shall not ask :/