# Deleted answer showing up in the review tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, deleted-answers

I just opened the review tab and saw this:

[image]

The answer in question  was already deleted at that point. Usually, I'd just put it down to caching, but here, the system obviously knows it's showing me a deleted answer I shouldn't be able to see — as evidenced by the question title's reddish background (CSS: `deleted-answer`).

This was the "first answers" tab, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this, however it does leave an edge case. Some times due to caching a we will have deleted posts in the cache, in these cases we simply omit displaying them during render.

The side effect is that sometimes it will tell you you are looking at 30 posts when, in fact, you are looking at 29. I hope nobody notices that.

Comment: "I hope nobody notices that." Subtle.

Comment: All right. Now that that's out of the way, you could look into why I was never notified of this answer and just stumbled upon it randomly. :P

Answer (score 7):

It actually is an issue of caching. While it's relatively inexpensive to check before rendering whether or not a particular post is currently closed and/or deleted, generating the underlying list of post IDs for review is a much more expensive process. So, if a post was closed or deleted since the list of reviewable post IDs was generated it's possible for it to still appear until the list is regenerated.

Now, as for why the system doesn't replace that post with another (or less ideally just drop what you can't see from the results), I'm not sure, although once upon a time [waffles was looking into it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76637/review-should-not-include-posts-migrated-to-other-sites/77160#77160).