# Can non-10k users see deleted answers in the review page?

Tags: bug, review, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Deleted answer showing up in the review tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108833/deleted-answer-showing-up-in-the-review-tab)

When going through the "first answers" tab in review, I noticed there were a couple answers titles that had the pinkish background color, like it shows up on deleted posts and in the flagging summary area, and included the summary-view of the answer text.

[image: Can see deleted answer in review]

Upon clicking "review answer," it doesn't show the entirety of the post, like it would for a non-deleted answer, but it just shows the expandable question pane, with no answer underneath.

## EDIT:

This question is actually a duplicate of [Deleted answer showing up in the review tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108833/deleted-answer-showing-up-in-the-review-tab) - please vote/comment on that question for this topic instead.

Comment: P.S. At the time of writing, I had 2306 reputation on SO, and I have not been able to view deleted answers (other than mine) anywhere else on the site, including deleted flagged answers (like the one in the picture).

Comment: (atm my SO rep is 8800) While reviewing a few days ago I flagged an answer and it was deleted a few hours later.  The nex day I was /review'ing again and saw the same answer; so I clicked on it but did not see if in the thread.  So, from my experience, it seems you can see them in /review but not on the actual thread.  Unfortunately, I didnt grab a SS or bookmark the link, so I have no proof, except for my memory (which has failed me in the past).

Comment: Now updated with 100% more real pictures.

Comment: @lunboks: Ah, that certainly would be right. (I did do a search before making this question, but obviously didn't find that) People, please go ahead and flag/close this for exact duplicate.